# Остановить основной поток, пока не закончится загрузка в другом(Observable)

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rxjava2

Всем привет!
Очень нужна помощь.
Ниже указан код, который выполняется одновременно с главным потоком. Мне нужно сделать так чтобы он закончио выполняться и только после программа продолжила выполняться в главном потоке.
Можно как-то это сделать?
Заранее большое спасибо!

```
while (totalCount > groupCount) {
                disposable = apiServiceGroups.getGroupsList(String.format("{\"offset\":%s}", groupCount))
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Consumer<GroupsListResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(GroupsListResponse groupsListResponse) throws Exception {
                                for (int i = 0; i < groupsListResponse.getGroups().size(); i++) {
                                    String currentName = groupsListResponse.getGroups().get(i).getGroupFullName();

                                    if (groupName.equals(currentName.split(" ")[0])) {
                                        Log.i("el1", currentName);
                                        familiar.add(currentName);
                                        Log.i("el1", familiar.size() + "");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                                Log.e("thro", Objects.requireNonNull(throwable.getMessage()));
                            }
                        });
                compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
                groupCount = groupCount + 100;
            }
```

Comment: Самое главное - зачем Вам это. То что Вы хотите сделать - это большая беда, от которой гугл ну очень постарался защитить свою систему. Как правило, останавливать главный поток - ошибка.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov просто массив данных очень большой и программа продолжает свою работу прежде чем нужные данные будут найдены для меня и, в итоге, дальше передается пустой массив. Я не знаю что с этим делать :(

Comment: Дальше - в смысле на другой экран по нажатию пользователем кнопки, или дальше - вызывается следующая функция, пока текущая еще работает?

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov  именно вызывается следующая функция, пока текущая еще работает.

Comment: В таком случае, Вам просто необходимо чуть тщательнее ознакомиться с асинхронным / реактивным подходом. Если вкратце, то любые функции, работа которых зависит от результатов выполнения асинхронного вызова, должны вызываться только после его завершения. Применительно к Rx это значит, что вызывать следующую функцию Вы должны из блока subscribe

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov просто проблема в том, что данный while лежит внутри метода onClick. К тому же, я не могу разместить последующий код внутрь subscribe, так как он находится внутри while  и будет выполнен больше раз, чем мне нужно. В идеале мне бы функцию, которая будет смотреть выполнен ли while и если true, то продолжить выполнение вниз, иначе приостановить выполнение и показывать PregressBar. Вот только как это сделать я абсолютно не понимаю(

Comment: Вам нужно запустить `Observable` ВМЕСТО `while` так, чтобы он генерировал нужные данные (у Вас это `groupCount`), затем операторами Rx для каждого значения выполнить запрос, оператором Rx все результаты объединить в `Single`, вызвать для этого `Single` метод `subscribe` и уже там, имея все данные, продолжить выполнение другого кода + отключить ProgressBar. Честно говоря, изучать Rx без опытного человека под боком та еще задачка...

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov спасибо огромное за советы и уделенное время, буду пробовать :)